# Is it possible to create two uint8_t pointers to the first and second half of a value pointed to by a uint16_t pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, cpu-registers, gameboy

I'm attempting to write a Gameboy emulator in C, and am currently in the process of deciding how to implement the following behavior:

- Two 8-bit registers can be combined and treated as a single 16-bit    register
- changing the value of one of the 8-bit registers in the pairing should change the value of the combined register

For example, registers A and F, which are 8-bit registers, can be used jointly as the 16-bit register AF. However when the contents of registers A and F change, these changes should be reflected in subsequent referrals to register AF.

If I implement register AF as a `uint16_t*`, can I store the contents of registers A and F as `uint8_t*`'s pointing to the first and second byte of register AF respectively? If not, any other suggestions would be appreciated :)

EDIT: Just to clarify, this is a very similar architecture to the Z80

Comment: Try a union... but pay attention to endianness.

Comment: it's also similar to x86

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a union.

```
union b
{
    uint8_t a[2];
    uint16_t b;
};
```

The members a and b share the bytes. When a value is written in member `a` and then read using member `b` the value is reinterpreted in this type. This could be a trap representation, which would cause undefined behavior, but types uint8_t and uint16_t don't have them.

Another issue is endianness, writing into the first element of member `a` will always change the first byte of member `b`, but depending on endianness that byte might represent most or least significant bits of `b`, so the resulting value will differ over architectures.

---

To avoid trap representations and endianness, rather only use the type `uint16_t` and write into it using bitwise operations. For example, to write into the most significant 8 bits:

```
uint16_t a = 0;
uint8_t b = 200;
a =  ( uint16_t )( ( ( unsigned int )a & 0xFF ) | ( ( unsigned int )b << 8 ) ) ;
```

and similarly for the least significant 8 bits:

```
a =  ( uint16_t )( ( ( unsigned int )a & 0xFF00 ) | ( unsigned int )b );
```

These operations should be put into a function.

The casts to `( unsigned int )` are there to avoid integer promotions. If `INT_MAX` equals 2^15-1, and there are trap representations for signed integers, then the operation: `b << 8` could technically cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Does this mean I would have to use: AF.A, AF.F, AF.AF whenever I need to access registers individually? And does modifying one part modify the whole?

Comment: @JoshThieme It does, but be careful. I would suggest you use the second option. See the update.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer. However, I believe that due to how some of the cpu instructions work, a and b be need to be pointers to integers rather than integers. Can this be adapted to that case?

Comment: @JoshThieme Pointing raw pointers is problematic in this case. Most types do not alias. I suggest you ask a new question with a specific example.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this:

```
volatile uint16_t afvalue = 0x55AA;   // Needs long lifetime.

volatile uint16_t *afptr = &afvalue;
volatile uint8_t  *aptr  = (uint8_t *)afptr;
volatile uint8_t  *fptr  = aptr + 1;

if (*aptr == 0xAA) {         // Take endianness into account.
  aptr++;                    // Swap the pointers.
  fptr--;
}

afvalue = 0x0000;
```

Now `aptr` points to the high bits and `fptr` points to the low bits, no matter if the emulator runs on a little endian or big endian machine.

Note: since these pointer types are different, a compiler might not be aware that they point to the same memory, thereby optimizing the code so that a write to `*afptr` is not seen by a later read from `*aptr`. Therefore the `volatile`.

Comment: Volatile has nothing to do with strict aliasing. If the types are not compatible it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You could of course use pointers to point anywhere you want.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint16_t a=1048;
    uint8_t *ah=(uint8_t*)&a,*al=((uint8_t*)&a)+1;
    printf("%u,%u,%u\n",a,*ah,*al);
}
```

You would need to take care of endianness as mentioned in the comment (
 I believe the gameboy is little endian, while the x86 is big endian ).

And of course as most poeple recommend you should use a `union` which would make your code less error prone due to pointer address calculations